# Python Tkinter: idlelib.TreeWidget folder color

Tags: python, canvas, tree, tkinter, python-idle

I have created a tree with idlelib.TreeWidget by using a simple example I found online: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/259116-tkinter-tree-widget-using-idlelibtreewidget/

I am currently running this example on Linux, and there are folder icons displayed nicely next to tree nodes. However, I would like to use different colors for certain nodes. Is that possible?

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from idlelib.TreeWidget import TreeItem, TreeNode

class DomTreeItem(TreeItem):
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.node = node
    def GetText(self):
        node = self.node
        if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            return node.nodeName
        elif node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            return node.nodeValue
    def IsExpandable(self):
        node = self.node
        return node.hasChildNodes()
    def GetSubList(self):
        parent = self.node
        children = parent.childNodes
        prelist = [DomTreeItem(node) for node in children]
        itemlist = [item for item in prelist if item.GetText().strip()]
        return itemlist

data = '''
<a>
 <b>
  <c>d</c>
  <c>e</c>
 </b>
 <b>
  <c>f</c>
 </b>
</a>
'''

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.config(bg='white')
canvas.pack()
dom = parseString(data)
item = DomTreeItem(dom.documentElement)
node = TreeNode(canvas, None, item)
node.update()
node.expand()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out we can use TreeWidget's build in function GetIconName(). This function customizes the icons.

So available icons depend on icons you have in /idlelib/Icons/

The following example makes sure non-expandable items would have an opened folder:

```
class DomTreeItem(TreeItem):
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.node = node
    def GetText(self):
        node = self.node
        if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            return node.nodeName
        elif node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            return node.nodeValue
    def IsExpandable(self):
        node = self.node
        return node.hasChildNodes()
    def GetSubList(self):
        parent = self.node
        children = parent.childNodes
        prelist = [DomTreeItem(node) for node in children]
        itemlist = [item for item in prelist if item.GetText().strip()]
        return itemlist
    def OnDoubleClick(self):
        print "double-clicked"
    def GetIconName(self):
        if not self.IsExpandable():
            return "openfolder"
```